# Wait for a web element while continuing testing

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

Is there a way to wait for a web element, while continuing testing?

For example, you have a web page with a search box and a tab of results, every search takes around 15 minutes each, but it can be more.

A new record shows up on the results tab when the results came back.

Is there any way to continue sending queries while "observing" for the results?
I need to update online a GUI on every search that returns results.

Comment: You can multi-thread your operations... one thread per driver/browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practices state that tests should be hermetic, i.e. independent and self-sufficient. So usually we try not to chain different tests. In your case where

> every search takes around 15 minutes each

most likely means that each search is a test of its own. Simple and pragmatic way to

> continue sending queries while "observing" for the results

would be to leverage parallel test execution. Each thread manages its own Selenium Webdriver life cycle, steps and expected results.